# Web application Autocomplete Extender is not working

Tags: c#, .net, web

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzjNY.png)
When text is entered into a textbox in that way, an error occurs above image . I tried every remedy, but the current one is the only one that isn't functioning. I couldn't figure out where my error was.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.